# Discrete random walk bounded in an interval

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose I have a discrete random walk with equal probabilities, and the particle begins at $x=0$. The process goes on indefinitely. What is the probability that the particle will never leave $[-n,n]$, where $n \in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You will stay in that interval in infinitely many steps with probability $0$. In fact, with probability $1$ the walk visits every point infinitely many times.

Proving this is a bit long for this site, but there's a survey paper that discusses random walks [here](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/RW.pdf).

Comment: I have tried to find this via Google. Could you help me with the right query to search? And if you could do the sketch, that could be really helpful

Comment: @Joshhh edited with a link